# Add admob, resize views instead of overlaying on top of views like iAd behavior through code - iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob, iad

I add admob using this code, calling loadAdmob() in viewDidLoad(). The problem is it overlays existing views. How can I add admob programmatically, so it will behave like iAd, resizing views when added.

The Test UIView is a button.

[image: iAd resizes view]

The code uses admob smart banner and works accordingly except the overlaying part.

**Portrait**

[image: Admob Overlay1]

**Landscape**
[image: Admob Overlay2]

**Code**

```
var gadBannerView:GADBannerView = GADBannerView()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

func loadAdmob() {

    gadBannerView = appDelegate.gadBannerView
    let origin: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, view.frame.size.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height)

    gadBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait, origin: origin)

    gadBannerView.adUnitID = appDelegate.admobAdUnit

    gadBannerView.rootViewController = self
    gadBannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())

    view.addSubview(gadBannerView)


    for view in self.view.subviews {
        print(view)


        print("")
    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if view.bounds.size.width < view.bounds.size.height {
        self.gadBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait

        let bannerCenter = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2 , view.frame.size.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height / 2)
        self.gadBannerView.center = bannerCenter


    }
    else {
        self.gadBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape

        let bannerCenter = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2 , view.frame.size.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape).height / 2)

        self.gadBannerView.center = bannerCenter

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to setup some Auto Layout parameters. You won't get the free resizing that iAd's `canDisplayBannerAds` gives you.

Comment: can you give like a code example for an auto layout parameters that would work with my goal? I tried it before but I wasn't able to make it work. I might be doing something wrong since I'm not really used to giving auto layout parameters through code. I'm guessing it was the top auto-layout parameter part. I was getting the same response. It would be awesome to get a generic code that automatically figures out the bottom view and work just like

    canDisplayBannerAds 

response. 
Thanks!